# Update SQL query with Select

Tags: sql, sql-update

How can I perform the below SQL query?

```
Update my_table 
set columnA = 1 
where columnID in (select columnID, count(columnID) 
                   from my_table  
                   group by columnID 
                   having count(columnID) = 1)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just remove the count from the subselect, and you should be fine. For future reference, please always post the error message you receive.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You have to match field counts on both sides of comparison. In this case you can remove `count(*)`, because you do not need to select it to use it in `having` clause.

```
Update my_table 
set columnA = 1 
where columnID in (select columnID 
                   from my_table 
                   group by columnID     
                   having count(columnID) = 1)
```

Comment: İ am glad help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query

```
UPDATE t 
SET    columnA = 1 
FROM   my_table t 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT columnid, 
                      Count(columnid) 
               FROM   my_table t1 
               WHERE  t1.columnid = t.columnid 
               GROUP  BY columnid 
               HAVING Count(columnid) = 1)
```